# Does compiling with gcc flag -fno-exceptions reduce the size of the executable binary?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

While reading the section about exception handling and the compiler flag `-fno-exceptions` in the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html), I came across the following lines:

> Exception handling overhead can be measured in the size of the
> executable binary, and varies with the capabilities of the underlying
> operating system and specific configuration of the C++ compiler. On
> recent hardware with GNU system software of the same age, the combined
> code and data size overhead for enabling exception handling is around
> 7%.

I tried to reproduce this overhead by compiling some simple C++ programs (without exception throwing code) using Ubuntu 20.04 and gcc 10.3.0 both with and without the `-fno-exceptions` flag, but could not observe any difference whatsoever regarding the size of the compiled binary executables.

So I came to the conclusion that the quoted sentence from the manual is referring only to the binary that is produced when recompiling libstdc++ files with `-fno-exceptions` because in this case, every occurence of `try`, `catch` and `throw` will be replaced by `if` ... `else` branches.

I am not entirely sure about this, so here are my questions:

a) User code being compiled with `-fno-exceptions` only prevents using the keywords `try`, `catch` and `throw` and does not generate a smaller binary by itself, right ?

b) User code being compiled with `-fno-exceptions` can still be exposed to exceptions being thrown from libstdc++ functions, if these have not been (re)compiled with `-fno-exceptions`, right ?

c) User code being compiled with `-fexceptions` (the default) will indeed produce a larger binary because of the generated frame unwind information, but only when exceptions are actually used, right ?

Comment: Does your "simple C++ program" feature any exception-throwing code at all?

Comment: @Frank : no, see my edit

Comment: If the program does not have any *potentially* exception throwing code, then stripping all exception handling code from the executable is a simple optimization and no difference is to be expected. However, a multiple-TU program using RAII and compiling without LTO should definitely show a difference because the compiler can't tell if an extern function can or cannot throw.

Comment: Here's a simple example showing the difference: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/voGTYcbG6 (do note that the distinction might still get optimized out by LTO later down the toolchain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **can** reduce the size of the binary, and it often does for larger programs. However, it's not guaranteed to always do so.

> a) User code being compiled with -fno-exceptions only prevents using the keywords try, catch and throw and does not generate a smaller binary by itself, right ?

Nope, it definitely has an impact on code generation. However, exceptions do not increase code size indiscriminately. There has to be exceptions possibly involved for frame unwind code to be generated. There also has to be something to do during unwinding (i.e non-trivial destructors). If one or the other is not present in a given function, then `-fno-exceptions` won't make a difference for that function.

For example, compiling the following will clearly show a smaller code size with `-fno-exceptions`.

```
#include <vector>

void foo(); // could potentially throw.

void bar() {
    std::vector<int> v(12); // has non-trivial destructor.
    foo();
}
```

see on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/voGTYcbG6)

Notice how each of the following changes eliminates the exception handling code:

- changing the declaration of `foo()` to `void foo() noexcept;`.
- providing a non-throwing implementation of `foo()` in the same TU: `void foo() {}`
- moving the construction of the vector to after `foo()` is called.

> b) User code being compiled with -fno-exceptions can still be exposed to exceptions being thrown from libstdc++ functions, if these have not been (re)compiled with -fno-exceptions, right ?

Any exception thrown by libstdc++ that bubbles up into code compiled with `-fno-exceptions` will result in the program being immediately terminated. If that counts as "being exposed" to you, then yes.

However, keep in mind that a large portion of libstdc++ is implemented directly in headers, and your compiler flags are going to be applied to that portion of the library.

> c) User code being compiled with -fexceptions (the default) will indeed produce a larger binary because of the generated frame unwind information, but only when exceptions are actually used, right ?

Close but not quite. The code will be emitted anywhere an exception *might* be thrown. This includes any call to a function without `noexcept` that is defined in a different TU than the one being compiled.